# Is there any real example of dimension reduction of a hyperspectral image?

Tags: r, python-3.x

Can any one suggest me a real example of dimension reduction using any model like PCA,ICA or others of Hyper spectral image with R or Python language.

Answer (score 0):

Dimension reduction is critical when dealing with hyperspectral data and it is quite easily implementable in python.
Import the [spectral python](https://github.com/spectralpython) library and use **principal_components** function on your data to get the PCA result.

As for example, you should check out [this](https://github.com/syamkakarla98/Dimensionality-reduction-and-classification-on-Hyperspectral-Images-Using-Python)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have already done PCA, KPCA and some other algorithms of dimension reduction but need help for KECA now. And if there any package for KECA algorithm that wold be helpful for me.